# C function change value on return. Corrupted stack?

Tags: c

I ran into a very weird problem today.
Long story short, my function returns one value, the caller gets a different value.
Somewhere around my code I have a call to:

```
Message* m = NULL;
m = connection_receive(c);
```

Where connection_receive is defined as follows:

```
Message* connection_receive(Connection* c)
{
Message* k;

    if (c->state == CON_STATE_AUTHENTICATED)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&c->mutex_in);

        if (g_queue_is_empty(c->in))
            k = NULL;
        else
            k = (Message*)g_queue_pop_head(c->in);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&c->mutex_in);
        /* Until here, k is reachable and contains the correct data. */
        return k;
    }
    else
        return NULL; 
}
```

Here's a gdb run, I stopped right before the return and right after the assignment:

```
222         return k;
(gdb) p k
$1 = (Message *) 0x7ffff0000950
(gdb) n
226 }
(gdb) n
main () at src/main.c:57
57              if (m)
(gdb) p m
$2 = (Message *) 0xfffffffff0000950
```

Of course, if we try to access 0xfffffffff0000950 we'll get a segmentation fault.

If I change the function and instead of returning a value, using a second parameter to pass the value it works, but I would like to know what went wrong on this one.

Thank you very much.

EDIT:
This works, but it's not convenient. And I would also like to know why such strange error is happening.

```
void connection_receive2(Connection* c, Message** m)
{
    if (c->state == CON_STATE_AUTHENTICATED)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&c->mutex_in);

        if (g_queue_is_empty(c->in))
            *m = NULL;
        else
            *m = (Message*)g_queue_pop_head(c->in);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&c->mutex_in);
    }
    else
        *m = NULL;
}
```

EDIT2:
Solved. Thanks all.
The problem was a typo on the header file. 
I can't use -Werror because I need to do things which
raise some warnings, and in a large make output and large header I missed it.

Comment: I had that happen once.  `fin` showed one return value and the variable it was stored into showed another.  A recompile fixed it for me (didn't even change the source at all); best I can guess is a dependent object file didn't get recompiled, otherwise possibly a (rarely encountered) bug in gcc.

Comment: You need to boil this down to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem and post it - there's nothing wrong with the code you've posted; the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @BrianRoach, I'll see what I can do. It's kind of a big project.

Comment: You might see this behavior if there is a missing prototype for connection_receive() where you call connection_receive() (as the return value will be converted a signed int and back to a pointer again, since the compiler will assume the function to return an int)

Comment: @Victor so the prototype didn't match the definition?  Yeah, that's a nasty one.

Comment: @therefromhere No, it didn't. I accidentaly wrote connection_reveice on the prototype (lol).
As I wrote, I can't use -Werror on this project, and it's a large one. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. How is your `m` defined?
2. Has your caller access to the right prototype?
3. What architecture are you on?

I suspect that there is a mismatch with the types and that my question 2 is the crux of all.

You are returning a pointer with (I suppose so) 48 or 64 bits. The caller, however, thinks to get a `int`, which has maybe 32 bits and is signed. On converting back to a pointer, the value gets sign-extended.

Comment: +1, I'm pretty sure (2) is correct.  This is the reason you should always develop with the maximum compile warnings set (`-Wall -Werror` on gcc), since it'll catch this sort of thing.

Comment: yes, the lower half of the return value being exactly the same is very suspicious.

Comment: @therefromhere 
I'm sorry, I forgot to say. My "m" is also a Message*. Yes, the caller has access to the same prototype, I'm in fact testing the module. Neither -Wall nor -Wextra give me anything, it's compiling like a charm. I'm building and runing it on a Fedora 15, 2.6.40.6-0 64bits

Comment: Bull's eye. Thanks.
After reading your comment I decided to recheck the header file, there was a typo on the definition.

Comment: So module testing again proved to be very helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you push a malloc:ed object on the queue? If not and you instead pushed a stack object then when you may end up with weird behavior when you pop items.

Comment: It's a malloc'ed object. I edited the original post, and posted a equivalent definition that works fine. It's really strange!

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same problem and the root cause was the implicit declaration of the function connection_receive(). So it was defaulted to int which signed and then stored in m.